# Everything is correct, but it shows 404 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, crud

I create a normal POST, GET mapping in spring boot. It successfuly connected to the database(PostgreSQL).
then, I want to try this in postman tool, but it shows error 404.  How to solve this?

I tried to get method. but it didn't work.

this is my entity class

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import lombok.*;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="firsts", schema="public")
public class Entit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
        
    
}
```

this is controller

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.post.entity.Entit;
import com.post.serv.Serv;

@RestController
public class Control {

    @Autowired
    Serv serv;
    
    @PostMapping("/create")
    private Entit create(@RequestBody Entit enti) {
        return serv.create(enti);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    private List<Entit> getAll(){
        return serv.getAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
    private Entit getById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return serv.getById(id);
    }
    
}
```

this is service

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.post.entity.Entit;
import com.post.repo.Repo;

@Service
public class Serv {

    @Autowired
    Repo repo;
    
    public Entit create(Entit enti) {
        return repo.save(enti);
    }

    public Entit getById(int id) {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    public List<Entit> getAll(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }
    
    }
```

this is repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.post.entity.Entit;

@Repository
public interface Repo extends JpaRepository<Entit, Integer>{

    
}
```

this is the json query I gave in postman
 `http://localhost:8080/getAll`

Comment: Is there a context specified in the `application.properties`? If yes, you will need to include that in the URL. That is, `http://localhost:8080/<context>/getAll`

Comment: i used application.yml file and i didn't sprcify

Comment: try @GetMapping(value="/getAll") and also try adding @ResponseBody after Getmapping annotation

Comment: Another small thing: in the repo, the data type Integer is used for the ID. In the model, however, the primitive data type int. I would change both to the class Integer.

Comment: Have you attempted any debugging yet?  What happens when you set a break-point in the `Control.getAll()` method?  Does your IDE stop on the breakpoint?  If not, I suspect that your Spring application isn't properly scanning the packages to add the `RestController` to you application context.  This usually happens when the `RestController` is outside of the Spring application main package.

Comment: @tbatch even, I thought the same(spring application isn't properly scanning the packages). then. I add ComponentScan annotation, still it doesn't work.

Comment: @prasannajoshi I tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: @Twistleton I tried it, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

your controller methods are set to **private**, which means they won't be accessible from outside the class. So, Change your controller methods from private to **public**

Comment: I tried what you mentioned. but, it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, few suggestions here to unstuck you if possible.

**1. Endpoint Mapping:**

Ensure that your Spring Boot application is running on the correct port (in your case, 8080). Confirm that the application is up and running by accessing http://localhost:8080 in a browser.

**2. Request Type:**

Make sure you're using the correct request type (e.g., GET, POST). In Postman, verify that the request type for "getAll" is set to GET.

**3.URL Format:**

Double-check the URL you're using in Postman. For the "getAll" request, it should be http://localhost:8080/getAll (based on your controller's @GetMapping("/getAll") mapping). Also, ensure there are no typos in the URL.

**4. Controller Methods Visibility:**

Make sure your controller methods are set to public. In your code, they are not explicitly marked as public. Ensure they're publicly accessible to handle the incoming requests.

```
@GetMapping("/getAll")
public List<Entit> getAll(){
    return serv.getAll();
}
```

**5. Controller Configuration:**

Ensure that your @RestController (Control) is correctly registered and scanned by the Spring application context. Check that your Spring Boot application's main class or the class with @SpringBootApplication annotation is located in the base package or has the necessary component scan configuration to locate your controller.

**6. Public Access and Security:**

Verify that there are no security configurations (like Spring Security) blocking the endpoints from being accessed.

HTH

Comment: I did what you mentioned. but, it shows
```***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field serv in com.post.contro.Control required a bean of type 'com.post.serv.Serv' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.post.serv.Serv' in your configuration.```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I388V.jpg)Finally, I found the answer.

I add a class **WebSecurityConfig.java** and it's run. and it shows another error like bad request 400.

then I solved. here that is
just update the postman header, mark the **content-type, content-length and host**
and unmark others.[I showed here what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZrS6.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).